# SVN trying to commit already commited changes

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, commit

My problem is as follows:
I committed some changes to one file and my coworker wanted to commit her part also on that file. She got warning she needs to update before commit and so she did. Then she made one last check before committing and noticed that she was committing same code I have committed moments before(merged one from update). She did not change it at all. Also she made Clean Up on WC with no success. She moved problematic file out of WC and updated WC, and newly created file was fine. When she moved problematic file back, problem persisted. Then she did commit these changes and in next rev. code disappeared. Gone. We reverted and merged by hand but it is a serious problem since, if she wouldn't check, we wouldn't even know, that the code was lost between revisions.

We both use TortoiseSVN, SVN version 1.8, we have SVN server.

What could be possible problem, that this happened and is there a way of resolving/detecting it other than by manually in Merge?

Comment: Are you sharing a working copy?

Comment: Each of us have own PC, with WCs on local drive. WCs is not shared in any way. There is no network sharing for WC's folder or files, if that's what you mean.